# Understanding what period refers to in trader_rsi

Tags: php

I am using the PEAR extension trader for PHP and in particular the `trader_rsi`feature [Link to manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-rsi.php). Now one of the inputs is a time period but Im not sure what it relates to i.e. days, minutes etc.

At the minute my array of data spans about 5 hours so I am a little unsure what to input to get the correct output.

**UPDATE**
Just wondering if I have an array containing 100 sets of prices, would the period be 100?

Any ideas

Answer (score 5):

The time period value will set the periods used to calculate the RSI and is based on the data you supplied to $real. So if you have 20 daily values and set period to the standard 14 the RSI will be calculated from the first 14 days/values and from there on build on that as base for the next 6 values.